# How can we evaluate the performance of Lz0 vs Lz4 compression algorithm for zram in android?

Tags: android, linux, performance

I am newbie to Linux and I am trying to collect the stats of `lz0` Vs `lz4` compression algorithm. As per `Google` claimed results; it shows that `lz4` `read`/`decompression` is three times faster than the `lz0` `read` operation. Whereas `write` operation is comparable to `lz0`. So overall `lz4` is **better** algorithm than `lz0`. But there results were evaluated on x86. However, I want to test them on arm64.

So as of activity, I want to evaluate the performance (read/write operation time, latency in queue ) of `lz0` and `lz4` on linux. Please suggest some documentation and idea, How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

For testing lz4 on Android, you can install [termux](https://termux.dev/en/) and run `lz4` command:

```
~ $ pkg i lz4
~ $ lz4 -b1
-Synthetic 50%     :  10000000 ->   5859357 (1.707), 811.9 MB/s ,4280.8 MB/s
~ $ lz4 -b2
-Synthetic 50%     :  10000000 ->   5859357 (1.707), 886.7 MB/s ,4118.5 MB/s
~ $ lz4 -b3
-Synthetic 50%     :  10000000 ->   4560720 (2.193),  72.8 MB/s ,2539.0 MB/s
```

The following stats is run above Xiaomi Mi 10, with Qualcomm Snapdragon 865 SoC.